# Javascript Global Reference Error

Tags: javascript, window, global-variables, hoisting

I got this question in an interview and I am curious as to why the two output different things:

```
(function() {
    console.log(bar);
    console.log(baz);
    foo();

    function foo() {
        console.log('aloha');
    }

    var bar = 2;
    baz = 3;
})();
```

ouputs:

```
undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: baz is not defined
```

whereas:

```
(function() {
    console.log(bar);
    console.log(window.baz);
    foo();

    function foo() {
        console.log('aloha');
    }

    var bar = 2;
    baz = 3;
})();
```

outputs:

```
undefined
undefined
'aloha'
```

what is the difference in the way that `baz` and `window.baz` are referenced? I though globals were automatically attached to window?

Comment: I think the real problem is why logging `bar` doesn't throw error. At least I am curious about that.

Comment: Why did you need to post all that other code when your question is just about the difference between `baz` and `window.baz`?

Comment: cause that was what I got asked verbatim. I guess I could have removed  the other stuff.

Comment: The interviewer was trying to make it hard for you by throwing in irrelevant junk to confuse you. Your goal when asking on SO should be the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A ReferenceError indicates that an invalid reference value has been detected (ECMA 5 15.11.6.3)
>
> In practical terms, this means a ReferenceError will be thrown when JavaScript attempts to get the value of an unresolvable
>   reference. (There are other cases where a ReferenceError will be
>   thrown, most notably when running in ECMA 5 Strict mode. If you’re
>   interested check the reading list at the end of this article)

For further reading take a look [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/).

Comment: thanks for the link. that's the kind of in-depth explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because function definitions are evaluated before execution, variable assignment expressions are not.

Comment: So, why loggin `bar` doesn't throw error?

Comment: bar doesn't produce an error because of Javascripts Hoisting principle

Comment: I believe that var defs are also noted by the compiler before execution, however the assignment of the value is not.  This would explain all the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `console.log(window.baz);` is trying to find the variable inside window object where as `console.log(baz)` is trying to get a standalone variable, which is not defined yet.